# Iterator isEmpty() call causing noSuchElement exception?

Tags: java, android, iterator, hashmap

I currently have the following code

```
while (!visibleTiles.isEmpty())) {
    tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
    if (tile != null){
        bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);
        if(bitmap != null && !containsKey(tile)){ //safe to recycle if tile cache is not actively holding it
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get a NoSuchElementException crash on the line

```
tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
```

Is there a big difference in using the isEmpty() method and calling a hasNext() call? I know that hashmaps do not have a hasNext() call so I did the following:

```
while (visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
    tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
    if (tile != null){
        bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);
        if(bitmap != null && !containsKey(tile)){ //safe to recycle if tile cache is not actively holding it
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I know that I should just run the app and see if it crashes, but the issue is that it's difficult to reproduce the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Your condition is `visibleTiles.isEmpty()`, so i guess there are no entries. But you try to get the next element of the iterator w/o checking if there is one, and obviously there is none. That's why the NSE is thrown.

Comment: also, you remove the tile, so I think you want your condition to be `!visibleTiles.isEmpty()` but i'm not sure if you'll run into a ConcurrentModificationException doing it like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

visibleTiles.isEmpty()

just checks whether map is empty (or) it has any elements.

```
ile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
```

retrieves next element from iterator.

You need to do `hasNext()` check before doing `next()` on iterator.

`hasNext()` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext%28%29) says

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words,
>   returns true if next would return an element rather than throwing an
>   exception.)

so, if no element is available and call `next()` on iterator will return `NoSuchElementException`.

On top of this, I think you really would like to do NOT empty check

```
while (!visibleTiles.isEmpty())) {
....
}
```

Comment: But if the `visibleTiles` is not empty, should you get the first key using `visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();`?

Comment: @YogendraSingh: OP not checking for not empty, checking for empty, so for sure there won't be next() available.

Comment: @YogendraSingh yes, but is empty as you can see in the while condition

Comment: @YogendraSingh: Yes, but that still doesn't solve hasNext() issue if your looping the collection. If you are just getting one element, yes I agree with you that just !empty check may be enough.

Comment: @Nambari: When list is not empty, why should you check the `hasNext` if you are getting the `iterator` on the map within `while` loop? Please note, OP is getting iterator within the loop with the condition that map is still not empty(assuming condition is corrected).

Comment: @YogendraSingh: If understand question correctly, OP need to loop through the collection, hasNext() is on iterator to make sure there is next element avaialable in collection.

Comment: @Nambari: The next statement `bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);`, removes the first element in the loop everytime, making the map empty in the end assuming not null keys. I understand, there could be better ways to achieve the desired result.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but the statement in my code actually does use !visibleTiles.isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

`while (visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().hasNext())` creates a new `Iterator` every time it is called*. If `visibleTiles` is not empty, this will always be true, as the next method *of the respective iterator* is never called and the internal pointer never advances.

Iterators should be used like this:

```
Iterator<TileType> tileIt = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator();
while (tileIt.hasNext()) {
    TileType tile = tileIt.next();
    // ...
}
```

*The point here is that there may be several iterators referring to the same collection at the same time. Each iterator has its own internal state storing (not necessarily explicitly) which element was returned last and which shall be returned next by the `next()`call. This can be useful, for example, do perform some operation on all pairs of elements from a collection, where two iterators are needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use com.google.common.collect.Iterables class for empty check on Iterable values.

```
Iterables.isEmpty(yourIterable)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing while condition should resolve the issue**.

Change the condition to check not empty by adding not(!) in front:

```
   while (!visibleTiles.isEmpty())) {
```

EDIT: Sample code:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> visibleTiles = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    visibleTiles.put("abc", new Object());
    visibleTiles.put("xyz", new Object());
    visibleTiles.put("def", new Object());
    String tile = null;
    while (!visibleTiles.isEmpty()) {
        tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
        if (tile != null){
            Object bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);
            if(bitmap != null){ //safe to recycle if tile cache is not actively holding it
                System.out.println("Recycle");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the insight, but that was already in place. I accidentally made a typo

Comment: @kevinl: Are you still getting the issue with the corrected condition?

Comment: If I use the condition !visibleTiles.isEmpty(), I receive the same NoSuchElement exception. Look below for the correct answer using the hasNext() method

Comment: @kevinl I added a sample code to validate the concept. I runs exactly 3 times and print "Recycle". `This works to me without any issues as expected`. There must be something different.

Comment: yes it's different when you have to recycle over 100 bitmaps. your example sample above contains 3 elements. As I said in the beginning, this exception is difficult to reproduce

Comment: @kevinl: It doesn't matter. The issue is something different. In the above example, you are checking the size(empty), it means whenever it goes inside `while`, it will have one element minimum. Then you are getting a fresh `iterator` inside the `while` and then the key from the iterator. Since there is an element minimum in the map, I can't imagine issue in getting the key. If you would have been getting the iterator outside, I could imagine some issue but not when it is instantiated inside. If that is not the case and you are convinced with the other answer, please help me understand too.

Comment: Yes, the issue probably is something different. With a code library of over 1000 classes, I can't debug the exact details, so I have accepted the answer that solves my specific issue; which was to use the hasNext() method rather than checking the isEmpty. I think conventionally, you want to use the hasNext() method anyway. Thanks for your concern and let me know if you have other questions

Comment: @kevinl: The question is not at all related to your acceptance of any answer. The `hasNext()` is conventional when you have only one instance of iterator. In that case, I would not have been talking anything. All I am try to say is: if you are getting a iterator on non empty list, there is no possibility of any issue. If you got any issue, it must be something different, which you may still come.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the question you are asking (which has been answered already) but just as a side note from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.

You can avoid that you can go remove on keyset iterator (which ultimately removes entry from the map), instead of doing the remove on the map itself (that's modifying the map externally while you are iterating through the keyset).

The part of your code that looks vulnerable:

```
tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
if (tile != null){
    bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);
```

Example:

The following resulted in an `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();         
map.put("1", "1");
map.put("2", "1");
map.put("3", "1");
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().equals("2")) {
         map.remove("2");
    }
}
```

while the following removes the entry from the map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();         
map.put("1", "1");
map.put("2", "1");
map.put("3", "1");
Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext()) {

    String key = it.next();

    if(key != null) {

         String value = map.get(key); // you have the value and
         it.remove(); //you are modifying the map only through the iterator itself

         //... do stuffs with the value
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a good point. however I do not run into concurrent mod exceptions. Also, I need the .remove(object) method to keep the variable stored whereas the .remove() method does not return an object

Comment: @kevinl: As it says, it doesn't always but you cannot be so sure that it will never occur. Its better to avoid it when you can. you can call remove after calling next. Just assign the what next returns to some variabe.

Comment: the .remove(object) method does not return the same object as the .next()'s object. Hence, you can't assign the .remove() call to anything since it doesn't return an object either.

Comment: @kevinl: next() on keyset iterator returns the key, if you save it you can use it to get the value (which is what you want) from the map, and then invoke remove() on the keyset iterator. Which ultimately avoids the concurrent map modification.

Comment: I guess I'm not following, but are you suggesting the following?
    tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
if (tile != null){
   visibleTiles.remove();

if so, how would I get the bitmap?

Comment: @kevinl: I have updated my second code to reflect what I mean.

Comment: okay thanks. I already had an answer that takes care of the original issue. Your code to avoid the possible concurrency modification exceptions will help as well.

edit: i just tested it, but I run into illegal state exceptions. I will keep this in the back of my mind, but for now, this question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the good information on efficiency, I have fixed the no such element exception with the code from the original post by removing the isEmpty call. It looks like you generally want to use hasNext when you call next in the same area of code.

```
while (visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().hasNext()) {
    tile = visibleTiles.keySet().iterator().next();
        if (tile != null){
            bitmap = visibleTiles.remove(tile);
            if(bitmap != null && !containsKey(tile)){ //safe to recycle if tile cache is not actively holding it
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: also, in this case, I actually do get the concurrent mod exception if I initialize the iterator as its own variable outside the scope.

Comment: Still, twice per iteration you create a new iterator and throw it away immediately afterwards. It does not seem you really understood the answers.

Comment: Also, what is this code supposed to do if `visibleTiles` contains `null`? It seems this code would run forever then. (This is also true for the code in the question, but more obvious here.)